# Drawing partial NFAs with TikZ/PGF

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've started using LaTeX recently, and I'm trying to draw a few partial NFAs for an article; I have little to no experience with TikZ, so forgive me for asking something that is probably trivial.

I'm trying to draw images like these:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

(Those came from [here](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html).)

So far I could position the nodes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \pagestyle{empty}
  Partial NFA example:

  \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,->]
    \tikzstyle{state}=[circle,draw=black,thick]
    \tikzstyle{block}=[rectangle,draw=black,thick,minimum width=25pt]

    \node[state] (s) at (1,1) { };
    \node[block] (e) at (5,2) {\texttt{e}};
    \node[] (x) at (4,0) { };

    \draw (0,0) -- (s); % Start
    \draw (s) edge[bend left=30] (e);
    \draw (e) edge[bend left=30] (s);
    \draw (s) edge[bend right=30] (x);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But I couldn't get even close to what I want. I have no idea how to make the arrows properly.

Could anyone give me some help?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Ok, no problem; sorry. I've been able to position the nodes so far but I have no idea how to properly make the arrows. I'll edit to add a MWE.

Comment: Meh, I've been reading for the past two or three hours and this is the best I got so far... :( - I'll be sure to read the TikZ manual on the next few days. Some tips about the arrows would be welcome for now.

Comment: Have you tried the `automata` library with TikZ? It already includes a style that, for example, draws an arrow pointing into a start node. You will still be able to customize the node styles further to use rectangles, etc., but I would start there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a full answer yet, but this should lead you into the right direction ...
For details on how the code works, please have a look at the comments in the code, which only contains minor changes to your provided code.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{
        arrows.meta,
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \tikzstyle{state}=[circle,draw=black,thick]
    \tikzstyle{block}=[rectangle,draw=black,thick,minimum width=25pt]

    \node [state] (s) at (1,1) { };
    \node [block] (e) at (5,2) {\texttt{e}};
    \node []      (x) at (4,0) { };

    \begin{scope}[
        ->,
        shorten >=1pt,
        % draw corners rounded
        rounded corners=2mm,
    ]
        % connect the nodes vertical and horizontal lines (`|-')
        % (if you need to draw first horizontal and then vertical lines
        %  use `-|' instead)
        \draw (0,0) |- (s); % Start
        \draw (s) |- (e);
        \draw (e) |-  (s);
        \draw (s) |- (x);

        \draw [draw=white,{To[black]}-,shorten <=1pt] (e.east) -- +(5pt,0);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: This should lead me to the right path! Thank you. :)

Comment: Could you add some tip on how to get the arrowhead on the start of the pictures? I mean, there's an arrowhead there without the arrow line itself.

Comment: Hmmm--- `\draw (s.west) +(-1pt,0) -- (s.west);` works. A bit of an hack, though (the `1pt` must match the `shorten` in the style).

Comment: @Rmano, this is a good alternative. I have edited my answer using another approach.